ST7735 1.44" SPI TFT GreenTab: white lines/ghosting (no hardware fault!)
I have been using SPI-TFTs for a while now, usually the 1.8 inch 160x128 also with ST7735 controller. No problems.
I bought multiple 1.44" ST7735 square 128x128 TFTs over the last year. Today I saw that only one had a red tab, rest where green. "Whatever" I thought.
When I try to communicate with the displays, I get an output just fine, but the display won't go to full black and when I put content up there it has bleeding/ghosting and white lines.
The funny thing is, when I upload new code to the Arduino, the processor gets veeeeery slow during the upload and - voilà - the output on the screen is just fine, as if the SPI bus has to stop pushing data to the display. The catch: I don't have any loop(). I write the displays once and never again.
Image while "running":

Different lib:

Image while "flashing":

I am using:

Arduino Nano
Coding/Flashing done in VSCode with Platformio
Libs: ST7735 by adafruit 1.10.4
Wiring: SPI classic (CLK and MOSI), CS are pins 8+7, DC is pin 6, Reset not in use

I tried this without success:

all other green-tabbed displays - no change
I swapped red and green displays (to exclude faulty wiring)
tried using "Reset" pin
tried almost every initR option there is - but I think INITR_144GREENTAB should be the right one
tried a different lib: "TFT" by Arduino
tried only the green-display (removed code and wiring for the second one)
another Arduino Nano 168 and 328

The code is as simply as it gets:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h>

Adafruit_ST7735 tftA = Adafruit_ST7735(8, 6, 5); // reset not connected
Adafruit_ST7735 tftB = Adafruit_ST7735(7, 6, 4);

void setup()
{
  tftA.initR(INITR_REDTAB); // works with any option
  tftB.initR(INITR_144GREENTAB); // tried all, no difference

  tftA.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);
  tftB.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK); // here the screen has already white lines

  tftA.fillRect(44,44,40,40, ST7735_RED);
  tftB.fillRect(44,44,40,40, ST7735_BLUE);
}

void loop() {}

I hope some one has an idea.
Thanks.

I had exactly the same issue, Since arduino nano is 5V pin, and the display is 3.3V if you add 1.2K ohm resistor to spi bus and control lines except Vcc and Gnd then I am sure it will solve your issues. I did the same and it worked.
Thanks for your post, helped to know that I was not the only one.

you are the man ;) It really solved the issue. I guess there is internal circuitry that feeds of the datalines being held high, which overloads the circuit. Crazy, but makes sense! Thank you very much!
